# How do I convert Likert scale data to numerical in all observations in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with 38 variables and 98 observations of pre and post data in R. I need to convert all the Likert scale responses such as Strongly disagree, disagree, neither, agree, strongly agree to -2,-1,0,1,2 in order to do a paired t-test to see if there is an overall change from the pre-data to post. How can I convert all of the responses at once rather than 1 variable at a time?

Also, is paired t-test the best way to compare this data?

Comment: Am, you haven't really told us how the data set is stored variable or data structure-wise - which is important when answering questions about enumerating or mapping data to either transform or create a new data set based on it (immutable aka not destroying your old data is something you might want to look into).

Comment: No, using a (paired) t-test on ordinal data is not a good idea. A t-test assesses differences in the population means of *continuous data*. For alternatives you should consider asking over on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). See [paired t-test with ordinal data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191493/paired-t-test-with-ordinal-data) for a critical discussion and advice. In short, consider ordinal logistic regression and/or Wilcoxon's signed rank test.